# Quill not found in production

Tags: javascript, quill

I use webpack encore, in development everything works fine, but in production quill is not found. I check several times for the existence of the package in node_modules/quill
I've tried reinstalling it several times to no avail.

example of a simple file :

```
import * as Quill from 'Quill';
import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
var Delta = Quill.import('delta');

window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  const options = {
    theme: 'bubble',
    readOnly: true,
  }

  let quill, delta;

  // ...

})
```

**RESOLVED :**

> Change :

```
import * as Quill from 'Quill';
```

> in :

```
import Quill from 'quill';
```

Comment: Do you have it as a production or development dependency?  Have you checked node_modules on production to see that its being installed.  Are there webpack config differences between dev/prod that could interfere with module loading?

Comment: @DaveMeehan It is installed in "dependencies" of the package.json file

Comment: Maybe you can quote relevant parts of package.json and your webpack config?

Comment: Also, please provide the exact error message and where its encountered